# Tornado CurlAsyncHTTPClient over Https: Segmentation fault on RHEL 5.3

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, tornado, pycurl, rhel5

Has anyone ever experienced segmentation fault when using CurlAsyncHTTPClient on RHEL 5.3?
It crashes when calling an https url, but not with http.

Comment: I am legally not able to share the code.

Answer (score 0):

What version of libcurl are you using? It looks like RHEL 5.3 [shipped with curl 7.15](http://vault.centos.org/5.3/os/i386/CentOS/), which is too old for use with Tornado. The [minimum supported version of libcurl in Tornado 4.0](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html) is 7.21.1 (and newer versions are highly recommended - the current version of libcurl is 7.38).